# Custom Comment Form Error Messages

Tags: comments

When submitting a comment with invalid data, an error page is displayed which doesn't conform to the website theme template.

I've been trying to change this by attempting to display the errors in the same page.
I'm very curious to know if I can do this by not using JQuery nor JS for error checking.
I want to try do this through using Globals or Sessions.
I tried using globals to no success (till now I still don't know what I'm doing wrong)

Has anyone tried to do this before. Any suggestions or solutions are most appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you want to use js? Any paticular reason

Comment: @PieterGoosen The reason is that the captcha I use needs to check the validity of the captcha through PHP functions and not through JS